# Sharepoint 2010 .net 3.5 issue with being in same default web site as .net 4.0 web app on win 7

Tags: .net, windows-7, sharepoint-2010

I have SharePoint 2010 (.net 3.5) installed on Windows 7.
But the problem is I have other non-related .net 4.0 web form apps in the defaultweb site.
and SharePoint 2010 stuff exists there. I am getting errors when I try to create SharePoint site pages. The web form apps don't run either.   I believe the reason is because of the mixture of .net 3.5 (SharePoint virtual directories) and the .net 4.0 web apps are under the default web site.

Note: the Sharepoint 2010  is in a DefaultAppPool with a .net Framework version of v2.0

How to I move either the .net 4.0 web app or the SharePoint stuff to another default web site?
How to create the default web site 2??

Comment: You can always create a new web site under IIS/Sites and configure your .NET 4.0 website there

Comment: Thanks.. I did create a new web site for the .net 4.0 apps but it was alot work since many apps had  to be moved. I wish I could have moved the sharepoint ones..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Sharepoint 2010 to install correctly, I had to change the IIS appPool default settings from .net 4 to .net 2, Integrated and set 32-bit to false.. Then the install went fine.